# Como posso logar melhor o comportamento de alocação da memória usando recursividade nesse exemplo?

Tags: javascript

```
const yourself = {
  count: 0,
  fibonacci(n) {
    this.count++;
    **console.log(`${this.count}º vez - ${n}`);**
    if (n === 0 || n === 1) {
      return n;
    } else {
      return this.fibonacci(n - 1) + this.fibonacci(n - 2);
    }
  }
};

yourself.fibonacci(2);
```

Saída do script 2 1 0, meu desejo 0 1 2, para que eu possa visualizar melhor a estrutura de pilha da recursividade onde o último valor da chamada é o primeiro a ser liberado.

Comment: Ao invés de começar em zero e incrementar até 1, comece em 1 e decremente (`count--`) até zero.

Comment: Editei, dei um exemplo ruim.

Comment: Mas nesse caso a questão não é simplesmente inverter a ordem, você vai ter que alterar um pouco a sua lógica. Ou inserir os resultados em uma lista ou calcular os valores iterativamente.

Comment: Você está imprimindo as chamadas na ordem do empilhamento. O que não está conseguindo visualizar?

Comment: esse seu codigo não vai dar essa saida 2 1 0 e sim o 1 1

Comment: use return arr.reverse();

Comment: Eu acho que o título da pergunta não condiz com o problema de fato.

Comment: @G.Bittencourt Valeu pelo toque, fiz uma lista, depois penso algo melhor.

Answer (score 1):

O método `reverse()` reverte a ordem dos elementos em um array.

```js
var fib = function(n) {
  if (n === 1) {
    return [0, 1];
  } else {
    var arr = fib(n - 1);
    arr.push(arr[arr.length - 1] + arr[arr.length - 2]);
    return arr.reverse();
   
  }
};

console.log(fib(2));
```

> Só não sei se seu script gera o resultado esperado mas a ordem é invertida.

Answer (score 1):

Veja se este log te esclarece.

```js
const yourself = {
  count: 0,
  log: [],
  
  fibonacci(n) {
    if (this.count === 0) this.log = [];
    this.count++;
    
    this.log.push(`Chamada ${this.count} - n=${n}`);
    console.log();
    if (n === 0 || n === 1) {
      return n;
    } else {
      this.log.push(`Empilhando fibonacci(${n-1}) - n=${n}`);
      let left = this.fibonacci(n - 1);
      this.log.push(`Desempilhando fibonacci(${n-1}) - n=${n}`);
      this.log.push(`Empilhando fibonacci(${n-2}) - n=${n}`);
      let right = this.fibonacci(n - 2);
      this.log.push(`Desmpilhando fibonacci(${n-2}) - n=${n}`);
      return left + right;
    }
  }
};

yourself.fibonacci(5);
console.log(yourself.log.join('\n'));
```